# does not get swt text field content length

Tags: java, swt, verification

I am facing an issue while getting the text value of SWT text.
My requrement is to validate the text contents length.user should not be entered
more than 3 chars in the text field. I wrote the below code. The problem is
when I enter the first the value as 1, It gives me empty value.
Next time when enter the value 2, it give me the value of 1.

```
text.addVerifyListener(new VerifyListener() {

        @Override
        public void verifyText(VerifyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("verifyText()");

            Text text = (Text) e.getSource();
            String text2 = text.getText();
```

}
}

Following is my code. How to ressovle this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Text#setTextLimit(int)` to limit the allowed number of characters in the `Text`.

But if you want to do additional verification, this is what you can do:

```
text.addVerifyListener(new VerifyListener() {  
    @Override  
    public void verifyText(VerifyEvent e) {
        String oldS = ((Text)e.widget).getText();
        String newS =  oldS.substring(0, e.start) + e.text + oldS.substring(e.end);

        if(newS.length() > LIMIT)
            e.doit = false;
    }  
});
```

Comment: Hi Thanks. It works fine. Also one more question,if I wanted to update the text field inside the verifyText() method, how can I do? for example, if the size 1 then I have to display the text is 100. So my question is it possible to update here it self while the user enters?

Comment: @user414967 Why don't you try it?